# Counting number of occurances of in primary array A that are in array B

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the count of Items in array A that are in B and return an array C that contains the count elements.

array A is:

```
arrA = [{id:1,name:"Nairobi"},{id:2,name:"New Delhi"},{id:3,name:"Singapore"},{id:4,name:"London"}]
```

array B is:

```
arrB = [{id:1,id_fk:1,name:"Steve"},{id:2,id_fk:1,name:"John"},{id:3,id_fk:2,name:"Stella"},{id:4,id_fk:3,name:"Kemi"},{id:5,id_fk:3,name:"Kelly"},{id:6,id_fk:4,name:"James"},{id:7,id_fk:4,name:"Marley"},{id:8,id_fk:4,name:"Oliver"}]
```

Using **id_fk** in array B as a **"foreign key"** for **id** in array A, the expected output is

```
[2,1,2,3]
```

My implementation code is

```
for (let arrayA of arrA){ 
let count = arrB.filter(a => 
{return a.id_fk === arrayA.id}).length;
}
```

Comment: That implementation looks about fine. What exactly is your question? How to get those `count` values into an array?

Comment: @Bergi Yes Please. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You seem to know about `filter` already. Just use `map` instead of that `for` loop over `arrA`.

Comment: Are you sure about the desired output? That way you will still need the original data to know what each count belongs to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a `Map` and get the id as keys in the wanted order and reduce the second array for counting items with `id_fk`. As result take an array of the values of the map.

This approach uses a single loop for getting the `id` as keys and another loop for counting.

```js
var arrA = [{ id: 1, name: "Nairobi" }, { id: 2, name: "New Delhi" }, { id: 3, name: "Singapore" }, { id: 4, name: "London" }],
    arrB = [{ id: 1, id_fk: 1, name: "Steve" }, { id: 2, id_fk: 1, name: "John" }, { id: 3, id_fk: 2, name: "Stella" }, { id: 4, id_fk: 3, name: "Kemi" }, { id: 5, id_fk: 3, name: "Kelly" }, { id: 6, id_fk: 4, name: "James" }, { id: 7, id_fk: 4, name: "Marley" }, { id: 8, id_fk: 4, name: "Oliver" }],
    result = Array.from(arrB
        .reduce(
            (m, { id_fk }) => m.set(id_fk, m.get(id_fk) + 1),
            new Map(arrA.map(({ id }) => [id, 0]))
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A result with a hash table and new objects with a count property.

```js
var arrA = [{ id: 1, name: "Nairobi" }, { id: 2, name: "New Delhi" }, { id: 3, name: "Singapore" }, { id: 4, name: "London" }],
    arrB = [{ id: 1, id_fk: 1, name: "Steve" }, { id: 2, id_fk: 1, name: "John" }, { id: 3, id_fk: 2, name: "Stella" }, { id: 4, id_fk: 3, name: "Kemi" }, { id: 5, id_fk: 3, name: "Kelly" }, { id: 6, id_fk: 4, name: "James" }, { id: 7, id_fk: 4, name: "Marley" }, { id: 8, id_fk: 4, name: "Oliver" }],
    hash = {},
    result = arrA.map(o => Object.assign(hash[o.id] = {}, o, { count: 0 }));

arrB.forEach(({ id_fk }) => hash[id_fk].count++);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: for the order of the result set.

Comment: @georg @nina-scholz I wanted in the end to create a count property in `arrA` as follows `arrA.forEach((a, index) => a._count = results[index])`

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this. https://jsfiddle.net/6egs7uLy/

```
let counts = [];

arrA.forEach((item, index) => {
    let count = 0;
    arrB.forEach((item2, index) => {
        if(item['id'] === item2['id_fk']) {
        count++;
    }
    })
  counts.push(count);
  count = 0;
})
```